# Eclipse + maven + hibernate-tools Reverse Engineering error

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools

I'm trying to use the reverse engineering tool of the hibernate-tools suite to  generate all the model of the tables in a PostgreSQL DB.

I followed this guide https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-mysql but when I run the hibernate code generator, it shows this error:

```
org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.spi.HibernateException: Table(public.newtable) already has a primary key!
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

This is the **newtable DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE public."newtable" (
    "codiceFiscale" varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    nome varchar(100) NULL,
    cognome varchar(100) NULL,
    email varchar(255) NULL,
    indirizzo varchar(255) NULL,
    "idComune" int4 NULL,
    "idStato" varchar(3) NULL,
    "idProvincia" int4 NULL,
    cap varchar(10) NULL,
    "ruolo" varchar(1) NULL,
    "idAccount" int4 NULL,
    username varchar(100) NULL,
    rup varchar(10) NULL,
    "codice" varchar(20) NULL,
    "codiceNUTS" varchar(20) NULL,
    "codiceStatoExtraUE" varchar(100) NULL,
    "dataAbilitazione" timestamp NULL,
    "dataRegistrazione" timestamp NULL,
    "numeroRinnovo" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT newtable_pk PRIMARY KEY ("codiceFiscale")
);
```

This is the **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">public</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Other tables can be processed without any issue.
Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Solved **empirically** by removing the double quote around table and column names in the DDL

Comment: Is the DDL you show the newly generated DDL? If so, show the DDL in the source database as well.

Comment: @JimGarrison it is the DDL in the source database